# XLConnect not installing on 32 bit architecture

Tags: java, r

I have 32 bit R, Java, and Excel, yet XLConnect is still not installing. Here is the error info:

```
* installing *source* package 'XLConnectJars' ...
** package 'XLConnectJars' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-
installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'x64'
* removing 'C:/'
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
"C:\" 
C:.../XLConnectJars_0.2-13.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘XLConnectJars’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'XLConnectJars' is not available for package 'XLConnect'
* removing 'C:/...3.2/XLConnect'
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
"C:\" 

C:\.../XLConnect_0.2-13.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘XLConnect’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm not sure what else could be causing this problem since everything is 32 bit

Comment: Something is 64-bit. Hence the message "ERROR: loading failed for 'x64'"

Comment: I've set R to 32 and java is already 32, excel is 32. I don't know what else I should check but I am positive that R and Java are 32 because I had to set R to 32 to match Java to install "xlsx"

Comment: you need to install `java` then install `rJava` package, the package won't find dependency if you insatll java after. uninstall `rJava` and reinstall it gain

Comment: I've installed rJava before installing "xlsx" or "XLConnect"

Comment: So I'm using R version 3.2.3 and I don't think XLConnectJars works with the most recent version of R...